# NCLS-DEPLOYMENT-00040 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: deployment, ear, glassfish-4.1, payara

I am getting the below error at deploying the ear file into the Payara Glassfish server. The version we are using is Payara - 4.1.1.171.1 version.

```
[2017-11-03T10:32:39.751+0530] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=60 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1509685359751] [levelValue: 1000] [[

NCLS-DEPLOYMENT-00040

java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployDirectoryScanner.getListOfFilesAsSet(AutoDeployDirectoryScanner.java:177)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployedFilesManager.getFilesForUndeployment(AutoDeployedFilesManager.java:241)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployDirectoryScanner.getAllFilesForUndeployment(AutoDeployDirectoryScanner.java:132)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.undeployAll(AutoDeployer.java:515)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:413)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403)

at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233)

at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)

at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)]]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Payara - 4.1.1 isn't a full version. It should be something like 4.1.1.171. Have you tried with the latest version 4.1.2.173?

Comment: Thanks OndrejM, I have updated the Payara version in Question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, OndrejM.

I have found the problem and fixed. The problem is, we have multiple databases and whichever configured in the domain.xml file is not present in the local system. Once I have pointed to the correct database, the application deployed successfully.

Thanks again...